# reductive Lie subalgebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Suppose to have a Lie algebra L with a reductive lie subalgebra G. Let l an element of L such that [l,g] is in G for every g in G, is it true that l is an element of G?if not, there are some restriction on G that makes it true?

Comment: The answer to your first question is rather obviously no,
since if $L = G \times H$ with H abelian then every element
$l\in H$ has $[l,g]=0\in G$.

Comment: It is true.But If L doesn't decompose like that?

Comment: The fact is that I have in mind a specific example: L is the set of weight zero vector fields in C^n and G is the set of vector fields tangent to an hypersurface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, this started as a comment, but got too long.

If $G$ is semisimple, then every derivation of $G$ is inner, so
that the normalizer $N_L(G)=C_L(G)+G$ where $C_L(G)$
is the centralizer. In this situtaion Michele's condition holds
if and only if the centralizer is trivial.

However the case where $G$ is reductive isn't so easy.
A reductive $G$ is the direct sum of an Abelian and a semisimple
Lie algebra. The Abelian part can have (if at least two-dimensional)
non-trivial derivations. These will lift to non-inner derivations
of $G$. If we let $L$ be the semidirect product of $G$ with
a one-dimensional Lie algebra using this derivation, then
$L$ normalizes $G$, $L\ne G$ but $C_L(G)$ is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Realized I had misread the question.

The set of $l$ such that $[l,g]\in G$ for all $G$ is called the *normalizer* of $G$.  It's not particularly common for the normalizer to be the same as G, though it does happen sometimes.  There are a few theorems I know about specific Lie algebras being self-normalizing, such as Cartan and Borel subalgebras in reductive Lie algebras, but it's not very common and I don't know any general condition which guarantees it.

Comment: *L/G* is not necessarily a Lie algebra, right? Do you mean that the centralizer of *G* in *L* should be trivial?

Comment: thanks!are there restriction on L and G to make the centralizer to be zero?